# Cython cast PyObject* to object without increasing reference counter

Tags: python-2.7, cython

I understand that when I'm make casting like: `<object> p`, where p is PyObject* reference counter is increased. Is it possible to cast PyObject* to object without increasing reference counter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: no. Variables typed as Python objects always use reference counters. However depending on what you actually want to do there might be various ways to avoid reference counting. For example if you only need the cast temporarily for accessing a single property you can simply use `(<Foo>p).myProperty` which does not increase reference counters as far as I've understood ([source](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cython-users/lgD_ULbD330/F285K30XkBEJ)). This [whole thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/cython-users/lgD_ULbD330/discussion) in the cython-users group also gives some more insights into how to avoid reference counting.